# ActiveSync SendMail - Staus Code 110 Returned

Tags: c#, activesync

I am attempting to write a C# program to simulate an ActiveSync Device sending email via the SendMail command.

Each time I send the request to the exchange server...the response sends back status code 110 - Unknown Server Error

And in the Device Log I see the following exception:

--- Exception start ---
 Exception type: System.NotImplementedException
 Exception message: This kind of node should contain a blob, not a string
 Exception level: 0
 Exception stack trace:    at
 Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Wbxml.AirSyncBlobXmlNode.set_InnerText(String value)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Wbxml.WbxmlReader.FillXmlElement(XmlElement elem,
 Int32 depth, Boolean elemIsSecureData, Boolean elemIsBlobData)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Wbxml.WbxmlReader.FillXmlElement(XmlElement elem,
 Int32 depth, Boolean elemIsSecureData, Boolean elemIsBlobData)
    at Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Wbxml.WbxmlReader.ReadXmlDocument()
    at Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.AirSyncRequest.get_XmlDocument()
    at Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Command.get_XmlRequest()
    at Microsoft.Exchange.AirSync.Command.WorkerThread()
 --- Exception end ---

My XML looks like this before WBXML encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SendMail xmlns="ComposeMail:">
  <ClientId>1234567890122525636247547456</ClientId>
  <Mime>From: scaletester261002@abc.com
To: scaletester361001@abc.com
Subject: Mail Subject
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Test body
</Mime>
</SendMail>
```

I can successfully issue Provision, FolderSync, Sync, and Setting commands but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong with this request call.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The exception is pretty spot on. Its expecting to get a blob inside your xml but it's finding a string instead. Only this im not sure is which tag it's referencing

Comment: I believe its in the MIME tag.  But when I base64 encode the content of the MIME tag - I still get the same error.   Note: when I change the content to base64 encoding, I change the content-transfer-encoding type as well.   Is there a different way I should be converting the content to a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question finally.

The content of the mime tag needed to be CData not text.

Comment: Hi, this sounds similar to the problem I am having. I tried wrapping the mime tag in cdata but it didn't solve it. Can you please give an complete example of the XML?

Comment: Sorry I haven't used this code in while so I don't have a sample XML handy but I did base my code heavily on this tutorial:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361570(v=exchg.140).aspx    Maybe it will help you too.

Comment: I still haven't solved this but I think what I am doing wrong is passing the the CDATA as a string. I found some documentation saying it should be an OPAQUE blob. Do I do something like `stag(as.MIME)` and then `opaque(new Blob(myText))` then `etag()`?

Answer (score 0):

Cool, nailed it! After almost a year I have cracked it and implemented ActiveSync SmartReply in [Speaking Email](http://www.speaking.email) (my product, sneaking in a link here).

So I found I needed to send the outer tag and then use the `opaque` method of my WBXML encoder to encode the mime string. I just passed it as a string and it wrapped it in CDATA for me.

This is my code (using [Mozilla jsas](https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/jsas) library, which is javascript not C# but this is probably the only working code sample on the internet, so don't shoot me for that!):

```
        var replyMime = 'From: ' + self.info.emailAddress + '\n';
        replyMime += 'MIME-Version: 1.0\n';
        replyMime += 'Content-Type: text/plain\n';
        replyMime += 'To: ' + recipient + '\n';
        replyMime += 'Subject: RE: Test\n';
        replyMime += '\n';
        replyMime += replyText;

        var cm = ASCP.ComposeMail.Tags;
        var w = new WBXML.Writer('1.3', 1, 'UTF-8');
        w.stag(cm.SmartReply)
            .tag(cm.ClientId, guidNoDashes())
            .tag(cm.SaveInSentItems)
            .stag(cm.Source)
                .tag(cm.FolderId, self.info.activeSyncInboxId)
                .tag(cm.ItemId, itemId)
            .etag()
            .stag(cm.Mime)
                .opaque(replyMime)
            .etag()
        .etag();
        logWBXML(w);

        self.conn.postCommand(w, function (aError, aResponse) {
            logWBXML(aResponse);
            if (aError) {
                self.reportActiveSyncError(aError)
                return;
            }

            var e = new WBXML.EventParser();
            e.addEventListener([cm.SmartReply, cm.Status], function (node) {
                self.handleStatus("ComposeMail:SmartReply", node, true);
            });
            e.run(aResponse);

            callback(msg);
        });
    });
```

Here the the fiddler packet (using [EAS XML Fiddler Inspector](https://easinspectorforfiddler.codeplex.com/) - you have to get it if you don't have it!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<composemail:SmartReply xmlns:composemail="ComposeMail:">
  <composemail:ClientId>c5d53f22ce9885b3f293db25580e6f54</composemail:ClientId>
  <composemail:SaveInSentItems />
  <composemail:Source>
    <composemail:FolderId>9</composemail:FolderId>
    <composemail:ItemId>Qq7X_NiQVEqCD0BDywFI5QAAAAABDEKu1_zYkFRKgg9AQ8sBSOUAAHjcWVc1</composemail:ItemId>
  </composemail:Source>
  <composemail:MIME><![CDATA[From: mike@bewebnz.onmicrosoft.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain
To: mike@beweb.co.nz
Subject: RE: Test

Thanks!]]></composemail:MIME>
</composemail:SmartReply>
```